# Having a problem with seaborn python module

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I started today a personal project following a tutorial from here  https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/savvastj/nbashots/blob/master/tutorial/Tutorial.ipynb
But I already got a problem in the very beginning and I don't know why, it's something related to the modules I guess but I installed all

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import nbashots as nba # this will throw a warning if using matplotlib 1.5



curry_id = nba.get_player_id("Curry, Stephen")[0]
curry_id
```

I run this and got me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\carlo\Downloads\ye.py", line 2, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
  File "C:\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .categorical import *
  File "C:\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import remove_na
ImportError: cannot import name 'remove_na' from 'pandas.core.series' (C:\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py)
```

Comment: Maybe ckeck the pandas version you have installed.

Comment: What do I have to check? I installed eveything separately

Comment: From what i understands seaborn tries to import something from pandas but can't find it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60486125/i-am-facing-this-issue-in-seaborn-import This suggest reinstalling with pip3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60486125/i-am-facing-this-issue-in-seaborn-import

Answer (score 0):

Check what version of Pandas, matplotlib, seaborn is used in the tutorial and what is being used by you. If there is conflict, first make a `conda` environment with the specific version of the either of the `pandas` or `seaborn`.

for example, you can do:

`conda create -n myenv python=3.7 scipy=0.15.0`
once you activate the environment as `conda activate myenv`, you can search for `conda` installation of the packages. It'll check for dependency issues and install the new packages according to the version of `python` and every other package already installed. So when you'll install new packages, they'll be compatible already to your needs but you need to find the version of either of the packages.